# Does the Forge model.sync webhook have different security/scope rules than others?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-webhooks

We've been using the Forge DM webhooks for some time.
But when we attempt to register an adsk.c4r/model.sync  webhook, it gives a 401 error. We have all of the "data"-related scopes set in our token.

```
{
  "id": "22c519a4-0afd-46f5-b80e-3a718fe6b5a1",
  "status": 401,
  "code": "AUTHORIZATION_ERROR",
  "detail": [
    "User authorization was not defined for eso with system id: adsk.c4r and event id: model.sync"
  ]
}
```

Is there something else that needs to be authorized differently?

Comment: Please check if your access token has both `data:read` and `data:write` scope and your client id is added as an activated app in the BIM360 account's custom integration tab.

Comment: Eason - yes, we have done all of those things, and we still have the issue.

Comment: Matt, which kind of access token did you use, three-legged or two-legged? It seems to me this might be the difference between us. I used the two-legged access token to create a new C4R hook.

Comment: One more thing to check: Please check if you can access other BIM360 API with the same client id added as an integration app of your BIM360 account. If you're encountering the same issue with the same client id, please follow this instruction here to do troubleshoot: https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2018/05/31/troubleshooting-tips-for-accessing-bim-360-docs-and-account-admin/

Comment: Eason, we tried with both two and three legged, out of interest, no luck. We typically use three legged. Using the same credentials, we can successfully call the api to create the various DM webhooks, just not that webhook.

Comment: Ok... that sounds strange. It might be not possible, but one more thing to check: have you activated the Design Collaboration service for the project that contains the input folder urn you passed in the request body?

Comment: Eason - I'm not sure if our previous test had something wrong, but now we can see it working when using 2-Legged OAuth. It still doesn't work with 3-Legged. Not ideal, but we'll make it work.

Comment: Glad to hear 2LO is working for you. It seems not to support 3LO access token creating c4r related event, I received the same error message while passing 3LO token. I'm checking with our engineering team, and will get you back A.S.A.P.

Comment: Matt, I got the confirmation from our engineering team, 3-legged access token is not supported for creating c4r related hook currently unfortunately. Is there special reason that you want crest hooks with 3LO token?

Comment: We avoid 2LO entirely, because we feel that- in the AEC world where there are always multiple companies involved, that 2LO gives you too many permissions, and what we really want is to be operating “as a user”. Jim Q knows my rant on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for the delay, we have some backlog in the work queue. After discussing with our engineering team, the C4R related hooks support 2LO access token only currently. Sorry for the bad news.